# Why does setting my Rotate.z change all variables?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make a sprite rotate onscreen to show the player how their Jet is rotated while they fly.

Here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AircraftScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public float Altitude;
public Text AltitudeText;

public GameObject AircraftImage;

public GameObject Aircraft;

void Update()
{
   Altitude = Aircraft.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position.y;
   AltitudeText.text = Altitude + "ft";
   
   AircraftImage.Rotate.z = Aircraft.Rotate.z;
}
```

}

It changed all the values of the Sprite (x,y,z) instead of just the z.

I did also try
`AircraftImage.Rotate = new Vector3(0 , 0 , Aircraft.Rotate);`
and
`AircraftImage.Rotate = new Vector3(0 , 0 , Aircraft.Rotate.z);`

neither worked, what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your code: Aircraft and AircraftImage are GameObjects, and GameObjects don't have the Rotate method, so that code should throw an exception.
Anyway I try to help you anyway.
Try using this code:

```
AircraftImage.GetComponent<RectTransform>().eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, Aircraft.transform.eulerAngles.z);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I tried `AircraftImage.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(AircraftImage.transform.eulerAngles.x, AircraftImage.transform.eulerAngles.y, Aircraft.transform.eulerAngles.z);` but it seems to be doing the same thing? Also i dont know why my Unity isnt giving exeptions or compiler errors anymore? As of earlier this morning even if I leave out a `;` or something, it doesnt tell me, not even during Run. I will retrace my steps and see if any of the settings have changed.

Comment: Ok so i fixed it. I had accidently disabled Automatic Reload in Prefrences. Unity now gives errors. I again tried `AircraftImage.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(AircraftImage.transform.eulerAngles.x, AircraftImage.transform.eulerAngles.y, Aircraft.transform.eulerAngles.z);` but its still doing the same thing. So I tried `AircraftImage.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, Aircraft.transform.eulerAngles.z);` but still the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Your goal is to assign Aircraft's z-value to AircraftImage, right?
If so the code I wrote should do it.
In practice it keeps the x and y rotation unchanged and assigns the z rotation of the Aircraft.

Comment: Yea, I dont understand why it isnt working. The details are : The Aircraft is controlled by the player, attacked to it is a UI canvas. Attacked to the canvas is the AircraftImage. It is a UI Image with a sprite as the render. When playing, the image rotates properly (Inverted, but on the correct axis) until I start less simple movement. ie, flip upsidedown, spin, etc. Then it will rotate the image on all 3 axis'. If i watch the Inspector, it shows all 3 axis' changing at all times. x and y change by micro bits to start, but huge amounts after flips and stuff. And z changes correctly.

Comment: Ah ok, now it's clear to me.
The problem is that with the user interface you have to work with rectTransform and not with transform.
try this code and tell me how it goes.
If it works I will post a response with this code so that you can accept it to help other users.

Comment: AircraftImage.GetComponent<RectTransform>().eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, 0, Aircraft.transform.eulerAngles.z);

Comment: Thanks for replying again LOL. I just tried, and its still not working "sigh". I think its something wrong with my game, so I will remove the UI and try again tomorrw. But On paper the code works, so make it as a comment and Ill accept it. Just change `Vector2` to `Vector3`, you made a typo

Comment: It's strange.
Try deleting and re-creating the UI like you said.
I've changed this answer, so if you think it's valid you can accept it.
If you need help I will try to help you.
P.S. in the comment code I had written Vector2, but it was actually Vector3.

Comment: You left out the <RectTransform> part in the edited answer xD

Comment: You are right.
It was there but since I didn't set it as a code, the text between <and> was automatically hidden.
Now it's fixed :)